# why I do not get whole compliment of a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data set one is a subset of another one. I am trying to find compliment of smaller data set in bigger one. I mean a data set who has all rows in larger one whose not in smaller one. I tried to do that with :

```
        df3<-setdiff(df1,df2)
```

but it does not give me whole compliment data set. because

```
   nrow(df3)+nrow(df2)!=nrow(df1)
```

what is problem? I can't put my data sets because they are too large but here is their str:

```
df2

'data.frame':   8185 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ SAMPN    : Factor w/ 1867 levels "    4","    5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ PERNO    : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ PLANO    : Factor w/ 28 levels " 2"," 3"," 4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ TPURP    : Factor w/ 22 levels "(1) Working at home (for pay)",..: 16 14 4 5 9 12 9 5 3 5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ loop     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ ARR_MIN  : Factor w/ 60 levels " 0"," 1"," 2",..: 25 21 11 31 31 51 22 53 11 56 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ ARR_HR   : Factor w/ 24 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 9 18 19 19 20 20 12 12 13 13 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ start_hr : Factor w/ 24 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 8 18 19 19 20 20 12 12 13 13 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ start_min: Factor w/ 60 levels " 0"," 1"," 2",..: 35 6 6 26 1 41 19 29 1 46 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ walk     : chr  "-1.00383132952532" "-0.926581782419858" "-1.02631368170796" "-0.932791692585498" ...
 $ car      : chr  "2.07437681481379" "1.14501550876385" "1.11864841001179" "0.989597814702681" ...
 $ bus      : chr  "-0.766918118637934" "-0.955021318273173" "-0.936196906716972" "-0.995116987781044" ...
 $ MODE1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ utipassen: Factor w/ 11665 levels "-0.00013173196102555",..: 1439 10982 10259 11235 9871 5775 5387 9953 6000 10399 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  NA "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ HHVEH    : Factor w/ 9 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ VEHLIC   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ licence2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
```

df1

```
'data.frame':   14693 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ SAMPN    : Factor w/ 1867 levels "    4","    5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ PERNO    : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ PLANO    : Factor w/ 28 levels " 2"," 3"," 4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ TPURP    : Factor w/ 22 levels "(1) Working at home (for pay)",..: 16 14 4 5 9 12 9 5 3 5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ loop     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ ARR_MIN  : Factor w/ 60 levels " 0"," 1"," 2",..: 25 21 11 31 31 51 22 53 11 56 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ ARR_HR   : Factor w/ 24 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 9 18 19 19 20 20 12 12 13 13 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ start_hr : Factor w/ 24 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 8 18 19 19 20 20 12 12 13 13 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ start_min: Factor w/ 60 levels " 0"," 1"," 2",..: 35 6 6 26 1 41 19 29 1 46 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ walk     : Factor w/ 11665 levels "-0.000581433567566935",..: 5607 3104 6055 3192 1894 7541 9111 637 8958 8634 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ car      : Factor w/ 11665 levels "-0.00234049683698745",..: 11335 7668 7255 4911 8856 5412 4359 8146 6061 5818 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ bus      : Factor w/ 11665 levels "-0.00101509639366457",..: 4839 7258 6826 8249 588 2755 3725 720 2918 2526 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ MODE1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ utipassen: Factor w/ 11665 levels "-0.00013173196102555",..: 2135 9762 7576 10524 6412 8409 7819 6659 8758 7961 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ HHVEH    : Factor w/ 9 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ VEHLIC   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
 $ licence2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "23" "24" "25" "26" ...
```

head of datas:

df2:

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c("    4", "    4", "    4", "    4", 
"    4", "    4"), PERNO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Names = c(NA, "24", "25", "26", "27", NA), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), PLANO = structure(1:6, .Names = c(NA, 
"24", "25", "26", "27", NA), .Label = c(" 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", 
" 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "29", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28"), class = "factor"), TPURP = structure(c(16L, 14L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 12L), .Names = c(NA, "24", "25", "26", "27", NA), .Label = c("(1) Working at home (for pay)", 
"(10) Other, specify - transportation", "(11) Work/Business related", 
"(12) Service Private Vehicle", "(13) Routine Shopping", "(14) Shopping for major purchases", 
"(15) Household errands", "(16) Personal Business", "(17) Eat meal outside of home", 
"(18) Health care", "(19) Civic/Religious activities", "(2) All other home activities", 
"(20) Recreation/Entertainment", "(21) Visit friends/relative", 
"(24) Loop trip", "(3) Work/Job", "(4) All other activities at work", 
"(5) Attending class", "(6) All other activities at school", 
"(7) Change type of transportation/transfer", "(8) Dropped off passenger", 
"(9) Picked up passenger"), class = "factor"), loop = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c(NA, "24", "25", "26", "27", NA
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

df1:

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c("    4", "    4", "    4", "    4", 
"    4", "    4"), PERNO = structure(c(`23` = 1L, `24` = 1L, 
`25` = 1L, `26` = 1L, `27` = 1L, `28` = 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), PLANO = structure(1:6, .Names = c("23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28"), .Label = c(" 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", 
" 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29"), class = "factor"), TPURP = structure(c(`23` = 16L, 
`24` = 14L, `25` = 4L, `26` = 5L, `27` = 9L, `28` = 12L), .Label = c("(1) Working at home (for pay)", 
"(10) Other, specify - transportation", "(11) Work/Business related", 
"(12) Service Private Vehicle", "(13) Routine Shopping", "(14) Shopping for major purchases", 
"(15)Household erran ds", "(16) Personal Business", "(17) Eat meal outside of home", 
"(18) Health care", "(19) Civic/Religious activities", "(2) All other home activities", 
"(20) Recreation/Entertainment", "(21) Visit friends/relative", 
"(24) Loop trip", "(3) Work/Job", "(4) All other activities at work", 
"(5) Attending class", "(6) All other activities at school", 
"(7) Change type of transportation/transfer", "(8) Dropped off passenger", 
"(9) Picked up passenger"), class = "factor"), loop = structure(c(`23` = 2L, 
`24` = 2L, `25` = 2L, `26` = 2L, `27` = 2L, `28` = 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `?setdiff` (from `dplyr`)

> These functions override the set functions provided in base to make them generic so that efficient versions for data frames and other tables can be provided. The default methods call the base versions. Beware that intersect(), union() and setdiff() remove duplicates.

So, the issue is that `setdiff` gets only the `unique` elements of 'df1' that are not in 'df2' .  It will not consider the duplicate rows.  To get that, we may need `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("col1", "col2"))
```

If we are joining by all the columns, and if the column names are the same, just leave the `by` option blank and it would automatically pick up all the columnns

```
anti_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199993/discussion-between-akrun-and-hghg).